# Register service worker with correct MIME-Type

Tags: firebase, vue.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to register a service in Vue.js, so that I will be able to send push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

I put a file called firebase-messaging-sw.js in the static folder. I can access the file from my browser. But Firebase needs a Mime-Type of application/javascript, not text/html. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

The MIME type of the file downloaded by the browser is set by the server that is serving the file. This is not something you can configure from JavaScript or so but by the *server configuration*.

How have you deployed the application? Have you setup your own server or are you using something like Surge, Now, Firebase, or some other service?

Then again – sounds very weird that any server would serve your JavaScript (.js) files with that MIME type. Misconfiguration?

Comment: Is currently use the Vue.js dev server. (But it will be deployed to an Apache server.)